# how can I have a smoother process for USA -J1 and J2 visas?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens

I am in J1 category and presently in USA.
Last month I tried my J2 dependents visa process, it was denied and issued 214b. The reason might be that I mentioned duration of stay in USA as 1 year but my DS 2019 had only 4 months remaining.

Now I have a new DS2019. I'm planning to go back India for my visa renewal as well my J2 dependents visa process.

How I can avoid the drop box option for me, and walk in for a visa interview and take my dependents visa process in one go?

Comment: Can anyone help me here